# How to find indexes from vector1 in vector2 in c++

Tags: c++

i was envolving about a week with this issue, i have two vector for example vec1 and vec2, i want after search and find values from vec1 in vec2 return their indexes where only found for example:

```
vector<int>vec2 = { 1, 2, 2, 4 };
vector<int>vec1 = { 1, 2, 4 };
```

i want somthing like this pseudo code and this result:
pseudo code:

```
for i = 0 to vec2.size() do
return   vec1 indexes in vec2;
end
```

result:

pass1:

```
1     0     0     0
```

pass2:

```
0     1     1     0
```

pass3:

```
0     0     0     1
```

final resault:

```
0     0     0     1
```

---

My code (it does not compile):

My code:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

vector<int> find_index(vector<int>vec2, vector<int>vec1)
{
    std::vector<double> tmp;
    for (int i = 0; i<vec2.size(); i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j<vec2.size(); j++)
        {
            if (vec2[i] == vec1[j])
            {
                tmp.push_back(i);
            }
        }
    }
    return tmp;
}

int main()
{
    vector<int>vec2 = { 1, 2, 2, 4 };
    vector<int>vec1 = { 1, 2, 4 };
    cout << find_index(vec2, vec1);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you write any code during this week? Please show us what you have tried.

Comment: Divide et impera. Try first to find the indices (if any) of a particular number in a vector.

Comment: std::find is your friend.    http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/find/

Comment: @Satus for get the indexes in general we can do this(following code) but for get the indexes in my mean i dont know how to do that.

`#include <vector>  
#include <iostream>  
using namespace std;  

vector<int> find_index(vector<int>vec2, vector<int>vec1)  
{  
 std::vector<double> tmp;  
 for (int i = 0; i<vec2.size(); i++) {  
  for (int j = 0; j<vec2.size(); j++) {  
   if (vec2[i] == vec1[j]){  
    tmp.push_back(i);  
   }  
  }  
 } 
 return tmp;
}

int main()
{
 vector<int>vec2 = { 1, 2, 2, 4 };
 vector<int>vec1 = { 1, 2, 4 };

 cout << find_index(vec2, vec1);
 getchar();
 return 0;
}`

Comment: @Cheers and hth. - Alf can you writ me example, i can find indeces but my issue is repeated indeces

Comment: @Maria  please move your code to the question body, it is unreadable like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you have fails to compile for two reasons:

- Using `double` item type for the `tmp` vector. A `vector<double>` does not convert implicitly to the required function result type `vector<int>`.
- The standard library does not define output of vectors, so the `cout <<` *a vector* in `main` doesn't compile.

To output the vector you can define function like this:

```
void write_to( ostream& stream, vector<int> const& v )
{
    for( int i = 0; i < int( v.size() ); ++i )
    {
        stream << (i > 0? " " : "") << v[i];
    }
}
```

and call it like this:

```
write_to( cout, find_index(vec2, vec1) );
cout << "\n";
```

It's also possible to write a little glue code that would enable the `cout <<` notation, i.e. that would make it use the `write_to` function, but that is maybe just complication now.

With these changes your code compiles and outputs

```
0 1 2 3
```

Comment: Thanks for correction my code it was useful but my issue has remain yet, and i don't know how to find repeated indecs in each pass and replace them with 1, do youhave any idea?